# VS ERROR: libconfig.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _S_ISDIR referenced in function _config_read_file

Tags: libconfig

Download libconfig from http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html.
But there is error on windows.
 libconfig.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _S_ISDIR referenced in function _config_read_file

Answer (score 1):

S_ISDIR is defined in ,which is in linux system.so, if use it in function _config_read_file", you should define S_ISDIR in libconfig like this.

## #define S_ISDIR(m) (((m) & 0170000) == (0040000))